# ipod touch apps won't start after update

Tags: ipod-touch, ios

I updated my 3rd gen iPod Touch to 4.3.3, and now almost none of the apps will run - they appear to start, and then exit back to the desktop.

A double-tap on the home button shows them running, but switching to them produces the same results.

Is this a known issue?  Any way to fix it?

Comment: Try rebooting your iPod Touch by holding down the power and home buttons until you see the Apple logo.  (Keep holding them through the part where it says "slide to power off".)  Did that help?

Comment: Nope, I tried that and the behavior was the same.

Comment: What settings were there in the iPhone before the update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend following these steps to restore your iPod Touch: http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1414

In short, when you connect your device, go to the device's Summary tab in iTunes and click the Restore button.  It should prompt you to back up your device first.

Comment: A restore seems to have fixed it.  However, it seems that the ipod (ok, it wasn't really mine - it's my sons) has been bounced between two profiles. I wonder if there's something new in 4.3.3 that validates that the app was purchased by the current user?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, and it seems to be solved after entering the app store, and clicking Update All.